# How to remove each object of certain type from array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Within my Angular controller I have created a method which is attached to a click handler on my scope. This click handler checks to see whether a checkbox is checked or unchecked and either pulls the associated objects out of an array or puts them back in.

My `else` block, where I push objects back into the array, works great. However, my `if` block where I attempt to `splice` these objects from the array does not work.

Here's the relevant code:

```
vm.checkToggle = function(isChecked, value) {
  if (!isChecked) {
    var length = vm.markers.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      if (vm.markers[i].type === value) {
        vm.markers.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
  } else {
  ...
};
```

I believe what is happening is that my array's length shrinks each time I `splice` from it, so I inevitably run into a `Cannot read property 'type' of undefined` error halfway through the loop. How could I go about handling removing these objects from the array without running into this issue?

Comment: Iterate backwards over the array so your indexes don't change.

Comment: @GeorgettePincin, thank you! `for (var i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)` worked like a charm! If you want to toss that up as an answer I'd love to give you credit for your help.

Comment: A simple solution to this would be to use **[Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**.

Comment: No problem at all. I actually was asked this for a coding challenge during an interview once...so good for you to run into it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate backwards over the array so your indexes don't shift. Something like this (not tested)

```
vm.checkToggle = function(isChecked, value) {
  if (!isChecked) {
    var length = vm.markers.length;
    for (var i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (vm.markers[i].type === value) {
        vm.markers.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
  } else {
  ...
};
```